# On what object Reentrant lock aquire lock on?

Tags: multithreading, java.util.concurrent, reentrantlock

Hello I have question about ReentrantLocks in Concurrent package.

```
//First
Object ob = new Object();
synchronized(ob){

}

//Second
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
lock.lock();
try{

}
finally{
lock.unlock();
}
```

It says both Pieces of code are equivalent. What I don't get is in Fist piece synchronized block acquires the lock on obj object. But on what object does Reentrant lock acquire the lock on? Can I specify the object I want to lock on just like synchronized(obj)?

Answer (score 0):

Diving through the OpenJDK source (I started from http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java#ReentrantLock.lock%28%29), it ends up using an `unsafe.compareAndSetInt` if you've used the default `ReentrantLock` constructor. So although the code examples you list are functionally equivalent, they are not necessarily guaranteeing the same implementation.